# Spool Unicode data in sqlplus to ISO-client without character set conversion

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, utf-8, unicode, nls

I'm currently facing the following problem:

We have an Oracle 11g database with character set AL32UTF8, and an sqlplus-client with NLS_LANG=GERMAN_GERMANY.WE8ISO8859P1.
Stored in the database are various non-ISO8859-1 characters.

Now, when the client connects to the database and tries to spool these special characters, a character set conversion takes place according to the client's NLS_LANG setting and the special characters are lost.

Unfortunately, changing the client-NLS_LANG isn't easily possible (legacy application - it's complicated...).

Is there an easy, or standard way to spool this data without losing these special characters?

I've thought about encoding the data in base64, spooling it, and then decoding it client-side.

But is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Without setting NLS_LANG it's going to be tough.

How good are you at simple coding or parsing/manipulating strings?

You can do:

```
select DUMP(field) from table;
```

Then write some sort of conversion code to parse the comma-delimited numbers from the dump into Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `NLS_LANG` value simply on command line:

```
SET NLS_LANG=GERMAN_GERMANY.AL32UTF8
```

The NLS_LANG value persist for this window as long as the window stays open.

Note, when you set `NLS_LANG` then it **does not** have any effect on character set which is used by sqlplus!

sqlplus inherits character set from current command line, i.e. you have to change this also:

```
C:\>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\>SET NLS_LANG=GERMAN_GERMANY.AL32UTF8

C:\>sqlplus ...
```

Here a list of MS [Code Page Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756.aspx)